# Proving open set without Cauchy-Schwarz or Preimage

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Edit:** Please prove this without using Cauchy-Schwarz or Preimage. (Also, please show *how* a chosen $ \epsilon $ would work by proving that $B(\mathbf x, \epsilon)\subseteq\Omega $)

I've been having trouble proving the following set is **open** without  the use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

$$ \Omega = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x+y\ne0 \} $$

Our definition of **open** is:

> A set $S $ is open $ \iff $ every point is an interior point (i.e. $ \forall \mathbf x\in S $ there exists $\epsilon >0 $ such that $ B(\mathbf x,\epsilon)\subseteq S) $

I have seen a proof for this using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality  however I am not very familiar with it so I would appreciate if someone could share a simpler way to prove this statement. (I am familiar with the regular triangle inequality $ ||\mathbf a+\mathbf b|| \le ||\mathbf a|| + \mathbf||\mathbf b || $)

I'm also not very familiar with much of the terminology associated with metric spaces since I am only doing an introductory course to Analysis at the moment, so apologies if any part of this description is ambiguous or unclear.

**My Attempt**

Suppose $\mathbf x =(x,y)\in \Omega$. We need to prove it is an interior point.

Geometrically, it is clear that taking the radius for the ball around $ \mathbf x $ as $ \epsilon=\frac{|x+y |}{\sqrt{2}} $ will work. (The perpendicular distance from the point to the line $ x+y=0 $).

However to prove this analytically (in case I was working on a similar question where I did not have geometric intuition to help me), I would like to show that

$$ B\bigg(\mathbf x, \frac{|x+y |}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \subseteq\Omega $$

So I need to show $ \forall \mathbf{a}\in B(\mathbf x,\epsilon), \mathbf{a}\in \Omega $.

I'm stuck at this point. My only guess would be to incorporate $$ ||\mathbf x - \mathbf a || < \epsilon  $$ at some point but honestly I have no idea.

Comment: Do you know about the properties of  continuous functions?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with continuous functions, however

I forgot to mention, I would like to prove this by definition (Not using the fact that the preimage of an open set is open for a continuous function)

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Is it okay now? I'm not very familiar with posting on MSE, please let me know if anything additional should be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your life easier by choosing a smaller $\varepsilon$. Let’s take $0<\varepsilon<\dfrac{|x+y|}{2}$. Now assume $\|(x,y)-(x’,y’)\|<\varepsilon$. Then $|x-x’|<\varepsilon$ and $|y-y’|<\varepsilon$. Now
\begin{align}
|x’+y’|&\ge|x+y|-|(x+y)-(x’+y’)|\\
&\ge|x+y|-|x-x’|-|y-y’|\\
&\ge|x+y|-2\varepsilon>0.
\end{align}
The first two inequalities follow from the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!
May I ask how you thought of splitting up the $ |x' + y'| $ in the way you did? It would be really helpful to know the mindset/goal you had when doing so.

Also are $ |x-x'| <\epsilon $ and $ |y-y'| < \epsilon $ "standard" useful inequalities for these types of questions? Thanks again

Comment: Regarding your first question: well, mostly practice. But think of it this way: We already know that $|x+y|$ is nonzero, we have chosen $(x’,y’)$ near $(x,y)$, now we need to use that $|x+y|$ and $|x+y|$ cannot differ too much. Not sure that that helps.

Comment: Regarding your second question: Going from $\|(x,y)-(x’,y’)\|<\varepsilon$ to $|x-x’|<\varepsilon$ and $|y-y’|<\varepsilon$ we lose something (the inverse implication does not always hold). This is why we needed to choose a smaller epsilon. (And also how we avoided Cauchy-Schwarz.) In essence, we switched from Euclidean distance to Chebyshev distance, because that is easier to deal with. (I had to look up *Chebyshev distance*, because the name is less used in my language. I hope it does not sound scary, it’s an easy concept.) Not sure if that is what you asked, but yes, that part is standard.

Comment: Yes thank for this, it answers my question. It makes sense that taking the difference of points we know are close to each other will probably yield a useful inequality and also the requirement for a smaller epsilon when we remove information from a stronger inequality making it a weaker one.

Answer (score 2):

Why Cauchy schwartz should be used here ? (Btw, I don't really see how it can be used...). Anyway,

**Method 1:**
$$\Omega ^c=\{(x,-x)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\in \mathbb R\},$$

which is obviously sequentially closed, and thus closed.

**Method 2:**

The function $f(x,y)=x+y$ is "obviously" continuous on $\mathbb R^2$. Moreover, $$\Omega =f^{-1}\big(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\big),$$
and thus $\Omega $ is open.

Comment: @user523384: I don't understand the aim of your comment.

Comment: This is how Cauchy-Schwarz was used in a proof I saw (as you asked how it would be used). I was trying to avoid this because I am unfamiliar with it and wanted a way to do the problem without using it.

Comment: @user523384: Why doing easy if you can make it complicated ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure what sequentially closed means, we haven't been introduced to this concept in class. Is there a more elementary way to prove this? (Also without pre-image as requested above)

Comment: $\Omega ^c$ is sequentially closed mean that for all $(x_n)\subset \Omega^c $ s.t. $(x_n)$ converge, we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n\in \Omega^c $. But the fact that $\Omega ^c$ is closed can be seen also as $Boundary(\Omega ^c)=\Omega ^c$ (which is really straightforward as well), and thus is closed.@user523384

Comment: Get used to Caychy schwarz though. It is basic knowledge to every mathematician.